# When using @OnetoOne(optional=false) does the target reference always get loaded?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In this example from this [understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html) tutorial will an `Order` entity always be loaded when an `Invoice` entity is loaded?  Putting a code snippet from the `Invoice` class below for reference:

```
   @OneToOne(optional=false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID") 
   private Order order;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because if you don't specify the attribute fetch the default FetchType is EAGER.

If you want it loaded LAZY

```
@OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID") 
private Order order;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, for `…ToOne` mappings that is. `…ToMany` mappings default to lazy loading.